# Is there a faster way to validate (or way to bypass) AWS SSL domain validation? (Updated with Answer)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, cname

I'm trying to find a better/faster way to validate domain names for SSL certificates issued through AWS Certificate Manager. The 3 I've done this week have taken at least two days to validate and I am working with over 200 websites that will need to be migrated to our new server

I have requested an SSL certificate through AWS Certificate manager and I have added the associated CNAME to the records of the domain I am requesting the certificate for.

I've done this with two other domains this past week and they went through fine. The trouble is the length of time it takes to validate. The most recent domain that I added the CNAME to is still not validated after 3 days.

**------------------- ANSWER BELOW -------------------**

Hey everyone.  Thanks for your feedback and help but what fixed my specific issue was altering the "record name" value given by AWS.  For example what I got from AWS for a record name value was something like this:  _random-numbers.domain.com.  Previously I was copying and pasting that entire value into the host or record name in the registrar.  Apparently that was wrong, but I fixed it by removing the domain at the end of that value and resubmitting it. So the final format looked like this: _random-numbers (without the period at the end). When I resubmitted the CNAME with that format, I was able to validate the domain within 5 minutes or so. Thanks again for your time helping me resolve this issue.

Comment: In us-east-1, I just now requested a certificate at 2019-11-09T20:50:43Z using DNS validation.  The DNS entries were in, the validation was complete, and the certificate was issued all within less than one minute, at 2019-11-09T20:51:33Z... which is about what I expected based on past experience or perhaps a little faster.  You're not seeing what I'd call typical behavior.   In which region are you using ACM?  Is your DNS hosted with Route 53 or elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. It's the us-east-1 region for us as well.  The current domain I am working with is hosted with GoDaddy.  I have the TTL set to 600 on their account so I should be seeing the update fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The time that will take for AWS notice your `CNAME` `DNS` change is directly related to the `TTL` setting of your `DNS` records.

To avoid waiting for a long time, you should use lower `TTL` values on your `SOA` records

Also triggering a dns flush on google `DNS` also helps to reduce `DNS` propagation time. Visit https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache enter your domain and choose `CNAME`.

Note that changing `TTL` won't solve the problem immediately, it should be done before the changes.

Other way to be faster is using email to validate your domain ownership. Please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-email.html for how to do it. It should be almost immediate, if you have access to any email on that domain WHOIS:

> Email is sent to the following three registered contact addresses in WHOIS:
>
> Domain registrant
>
> Technical contact
>
> Administrative contact

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Elias. For the domain I'm working with currently, the TTL is set to 600 seconds in GoDaddy.  It's been set to that for 3 days at least.  I tried the DNS flush link you sent me. I appreciate that.  I would love to do the email validation but many of the customers we work with either don't have the default emails setup (ie, admin@, webmaster@, etc) that AWS sends too, or they struggle to gain access to them.  I appreciate your help and insight here.  I was wondering if we used APIs to setup an SSL through AWS does that bypass or automate any verification process?

Comment: As Elias said, this isn't an AWS issue at all and nothing you can resolve from AWS side. Setting up SSL via API will not change anything, nor is there any way to bypass SSL verification, you wouldn't want that to be possible. This is purely an issue with the DNS verification entry taking long to propagate on your DNS zones.